# is there a trick or a function to insert elements in a php string?

Tags: php, mysql, string

I want to modify the syntax of a SQL query dynamically
eg:

```
$var = SELECT * FROM schools WHERE teacher = 1 OR teacher = 2 AND student = 1 OR student = 2 OR student = 3 AND classroomId = 12
```

So in the above example I want to group the OR in a parenthesis otherwise the query results will not be correct.

I want to dynamically transform via a function or script that query to this:

```
$var = SELECT * FROM schools WHERE (teacher = 1 OR teacher = 2 ) AND (student = 1 OR student = 2 OR student = 3) AND classroomId = 12
```

is it possible ?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Don't forget your quotes around the value of var: `$var = "..."`

Comment: I want to modify the content of  a variable once there's OR condition

Answer (score 0):

You can do it something so

```
$arr = array (
   "teacher" => array(1,2),
   "student" => array(1,2,3),
   "classroomId" => array(1)
   );

function mylist ($array) {
    foreach ($array as $name => $arr) {
      foreach ($arr as &$item) 
        $item = $name . '=' . $item;
      $or[] =  '(' . implode(' OR ', $arr) . ')';
    }
    return implode(' AND ', $or); 
}


echo 'SELECT * FROM schools WHERE '. mylist($arr);
```

resuде

```
SELECT * FROM schools WHERE (teacher=1 OR teacher=2) AND (student=1 OR student=2 OR student=3) AND (classroomId=1)
```